# Zip a file before upload via http post request in flask

Tags: python, http, flask, gzip

Uploading is slow on a webtool I am making, so I want to upload compressed files instead. Is it possible to zip a file before it is uploaded (via an http post request) in Flask?

I want to use gzip with something like the following, but am unsure if it is possible to zip prior to upload.

```
    test = open(path_to_uploaded_file, mode="rb")
                    test_2 = test.read()
                    hi = gzip.compress(test_2)
                    new_file = open(session["file_path"].replace(".mgh", ".mgz"), "wb+")
                    new_file.write(hi)
```

Here is the framework I am using for file upload (source: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)

```
    import os
    from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

    UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

    def allowed_file(filename):
        return '.' in filename and \
               filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # check if the post request has the file part
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part')
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files['file']
            # if user does not select file, browser also
            # submit an empty part without filename
            if file.filename == '':
                flash('No selected file')
                return redirect(request.url)
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                        filename=filename))
        return '''
        <!doctype html>
        <title>Upload new File</title>
        <h1>Upload new File</h1>
        <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
          <input type=file name=file>
          <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>
        '''
```

Thanks!